# Why is a function with random monad taking an extra parameter?

Tags: haskell, monads

In a [tutorial](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/you-could-have-invented-monads-and.html) on monads, in the section **A more complex side effect: Random Numbers**, the author provides the signature of the random function like so:

```
random :: StdGen -> (a,StdGen)
```

but then goes on to say that:

> So a function that is conceptually a randomised function `a → b` can be
>   written as a function 
>   `a -> StdGen -> (b,StdGen)` 
> where `StdGen` is the
>   type of the seed.

Where does the extra `a` in the begining of the signature come from? Why is the type of that not simply `StdGen -> (a, StdGen)` as before???

Thanks

Comment: Those are two different functions. One takes a `StdGen` and returns a result of that random generator along with the new state. He then says, "so if we have a function that mutates an `a` randomly, you'd get..." and then the second signature.

Comment: Oh, ok got it! That random mutating explanation makes it clear. Thanks.

Comment: @GManNickG Could you put this in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the same because those are two different functions he's describing. :)

The first one takes a `StdGen` and returns a result of that random generator along with the new state.

He then says, "so if we have a function that mutates an `a` randomly (into `b`), you'd get..." and then the second signature.

Answer (score 3):

I assume it means `a` is the argument in `a -> b` and the random `b` is `StdGen -> (b, StdGen)`. `StdGen -> (a, StdGen)` would just give you a random `a`.